# How to put confirmation box on ajax submission form validation io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, formvalidation-plugin

```
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(e.target),
    fv    = $form.data('formValidation');

    // Use Ajax to submit form data
    $.ajax({
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      cache: false,
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("Your changes have been saved")
      }
    });
});
```

I am using ajax call on `success.form.fv` in `formvalidationIO`.

How can I add confirmation dialog box with yes and no options before I do the form submission?

Comment: see confirm() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the code to:

```
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    if(confirm('Submit the form ?')){ //user chooses Ok
        /**** Your AJAX code here ****/
    } else {
        // user chooses cancel. Do not submit the form
    }
});
```